# Emacs LaTeX formatting paragraphs

Tags: formatting, emacs, auctex

I like the Format Paragraph function of Auctex/LaTeX in Emacs but it seems to move markup commands around. Is there any way I can format a buffer but only the plaintext sections of it so that it ends up like the fill paragraph or format region commands but without touching LaTeX commands?

Just to be a little more clear, if the command(s) are on a newline I want them to not be messed with, so commands that are inside the paragraph such as `texbf` can be moved around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've written a quick hack to accomplish that in Emacs. The idea is the following: first, find the first "hard" paragraph separation (that is, two newlines). I'm sure there should be a better way of identifying paragraphs, maybe via some other elisp function, but I haven't looked at it. That separation will bound the area of application of the paragraph fill (`fill-paragraph` never goes beyond a hard paragraph). Then, we convert any "starting" TeX command (a `\` just after a newline) into a starting of a paragraph of its own. It is ugly, as it changes the text, inserting newlines for TeX commands that start in a new line.

*Note however* that getting the correct behavior is sometimes impossible. For instance, if you maintain etiquette, your lines will be around 75 characters long *and* will end with a newline. By chance, a `\textbf`, for example, may start after a newline, but you obviously want that one inside the current paragraph.

This is the code. You can bind it to M-q when in TeX/LaTeX mode:

```lisp
(defun latex-fill-paragraph ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    ;; Insert a newline before a TeX command starting a line to avoid
    ;; fill-paragraph to include it in the current paragraph
    (let ((end-point
           (or
            (save-excursion
              (re-search-forward "\n\n" (point-max) t))
            (point-max))))
      (replace-regexp "\n\\\\" "\n\n\\\\" t (point) (- end-point 2))))
  (save-excursion
    (fill-paragraph)))
```

Comment: Would it be possible to apply this for the entire buffer?

Comment: I think so, you just have to use the replace-regexp to all the text, from `(point-min)` to `(point-max)`.